# What should I look for in optical/hardware resolution when buying a scanner?

Tags: hardware-rec, scanner

I'm debating between these two scanners:

1. [Canon CanoScan LiDE 110 Flatbed Colour Scanner 2400DPI 48/24BIT USB2.0](http://ncix.com/products/?sku=56536&vpn=4507B003&manufacture=Canon&promoid=1078)
2. [Epson Perfection V33 Flatbed Scanner USB2.0 9600X4800DPI](http://ncix.com/products/?sku=54947&vpn=B11B200201&manufacture=Epson)

I've got some old family photos I want to scan and archive. I'd like high-quality scans.

I'm a bit confused about the differences between "Optical" and "Hardware" resolutions, and why they are giving X*Y DPIs; normally DPIs are given as a flat numbers. Does that mean they have a higher horizontal resolution than vertical resolution?

The interpolated/software DPI is meaningless if I'm not mistaken. I can blow it up in Photoshop if I really want to.

What should I buy based on these technical criteria?

Comment: I cannot answer your technical questions but I'm a happy owner of the Lide 110 since a few weeks back. I'm also scanning old family photos and I must say I'm very satisfied with it. Fast, simple and nice quality scans. You should really treat your self with a decent scanner software though, I recommend Vuescan.

Comment: Are you asking for a shopping recommendation?

Comment: @CGA: FYI, VueScan crashed the first time I used it, and did nothing the second but loop through the wizard over and over again the second time.

Comment: @wizlog No, of course not, that would be against the ToS :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word scan-head simply means the horizontal bar that goes up-and-down along the scanner (for flatbed scanners). It is static for auto-feed scanners.

**Optical resolution**

This is often given as a single number say 600dpi and is related to the amount of detail the scan-head can capture horizontally -loosely speaking.

Technically, it is the number of sensors placed per inch (horizontally) on the scan-head. In this case, there are 600 sensors horizontally per inch on the scan-head.

*Side note:* If the maximum paper size of a scanner is legal, then there are *(600 x 8.5 = 2550)* sensors along the scan-head.
some scanners using a single-pass might have 3 rows of sensors on the scan-head (this doesn't improve quality of scan, it only increases the speed).

**Hardware resolution**

This is often given as two numbers say 600 x 1200 dpi; the first is often the same as the optical resolution and the last is related to the quality of detail that can be captured vertically - again loosely speaking.

Technically, the last number is the number of vertical step movements of the scan-head per inch. In this case, this means the scan-head moves 1/1200 inches (vertically) per sampling - allowing for more detail to be captured vertically than one with a 1/600 step.

**Maximum, Interpolated, etc resolutions**

These are just software/hybrid means of increasing the resolution. They are not important because they simply add (gradient) pixels horizontally/vertically to the original scan (to give a smooth larger image); they don't add any further detail to the original scan

**Verdict**

Pick a scanner where the optical or hardware resolution is as high as possible.

*I know that the optics: lens, type of light source and sensor technology etc play a role in scan quality, but these are out of this question's context. Oh, and don't forget to up-vote if you found this useful*

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

[ScannerGalaxy](http://www.scannergalaxy.com/guide.cfm) has a guide for picking scanners.

The follwoing was taken directly from [ScannerGalaxy.com](http://www.scannergalaxy.com/guide.cfm).

> Choosing the Right Scanner
>
> When choosing a scanner, there are several key attributes that you
>   should take into account.
>   1. Color Depth: The number of bits captured per pixel, which is related to the number of possible colors. Higher color depth equals
>   better image quality. Typical color depths are 24, 32, 36, 42 and
>   48-bit. If you plan on doing document scans, then you may not even
>   need color. However, for those that wish to scan photographs or
>   projects requiring great detail, then look for a scanner with a color
>   depth closer to 48-bit.
>
> 2. Optical Resolution: A measure of how well a scanner can capture an image. It is the actual number of pixels that the scanner provides
>      when scanning an image. The higher the optical resolution, the higher
>      the quality of the image captured. Measured in dots per inch (dpi).
>      Not to be confused with interpolated resolution. 300 dpi will do well
>      for most office applications. However, look for at least 600 dpi when
>      photos are involved.
> 3. Interpolated resolution: The ability of the scanner software to "fill-in" spaces between scanned dots. This is really only a factor if
>      you plan on enlarging images. The higher the interpolated resolution,
>      the smoother your enlarged images will look. 9600 x 9600 dpi is a
>      typical interpolated resolution offered today.
> 4. Flatbed vs. Sheetfed: Flatbed scanners offer a flat, glass surface. The image to be scanned is placed on the glass surface and the lid is
>      shut. This is typically used for environments where very limited
>      scanning takes place or for "irregular" objects (i.e. a book or hard
>      cased object). Sheetfed scanners are useful for environments that
>      require frequent volume scanning. They allow you to scan large
>      projects automatically. Simply place the sheets that need to be
>      scanned in the automatic document feeder. The sheetfed scanner will
>      automatically process the sheets and scan them automatically. Scanners
>      offer various sizes of automatic document feeders. Larger capacity
>      feeders allow for larger jobs to be completed with fewer interventions
>      from the user. Some scanners offer both flatbed and sheetfed
>      capabilities. This allows for more flexibility in a single unit.
> 5. Simplex or Duplex: Simplex scanners have the ability to scan one side of a document. This is useful when a majority of your items that
>      need to be scanned are single-sided. Duplex scanners allow for the
>      scanning of both sides of a document in a single pass. A majority of
>      duplex scanners have a feeder with a dual sided lens that reads both
>      sides of a document as it passes through. Duplex scanners can be set
>      to scan as simplex or duplex, depending on the job the user wishes to
>      scan.
> 6. Scan Speed: Scan speed is typically rated in pages per minute (ppm) for simplex scanning and images per minute (ipm) for duplex scanning.
>      Pages per minute (ppm) measures the amount of pages scanned in a given
>      minute. Images per minute (ipm) measures the amount of actual images
>      (front and back) scanned in a minute. The higher the scan speed, the
>      more scans a user can do in a set amount of time. Look for higher scan
>      speeds if you plan on doing frequent or high-volume scanning. Scan
>      speed decreases as you increase the scan resolution.

Comment: Please quote content you didn't write. Your answer entirely consists of content you may or may not have the rights to copy. It would be great to summarize it yourself.